# Powering LED strip off a raspberry pi zero - works but lights at end of strip fade

Tags: power, led

I am powering LEDs off my RPIZero to use as an Ambilight clone.  My setup has the LEDs being entirely powered off the GPIO pin 2 (5v)but I have noticed that the far end of the strip seems darker and was wondering whether or not I could add additional power to the strip by also using GPIO pin 4.

Here is the setup I have right now:[image]

Comment: Unless this is a very short strip, which you have not specified, it is doubtful it can be powered from the Pi

Comment: don't use the RPi as a power supply ... the Pi can easily become an expensive fuse

Answer (score 2):

Pins 2 and 4 are both on the 5V power rail.  You can consider them to be the same pin.  Just as much power will come out of pin 2 as pin 2 and 4 together.

It might be worth connecting 5V power to both ends of the LED strip.